# sqlalchemy generated SQL not running on Sybase

Tags: sqlalchemy, sybase

sqlalchemy is generating this query for me:

`SELECT INSTRUMENT_GROUP.id_imnt_grp AS "INSTRUMENT_GROUP_id_imnt_grp",INSTRUMENT_GROUP.nm_imnt_grp AS "INSTRUMENT_GROUP_nm_imnt_grp",  INSTRUMENT_GROUP.type_imnt_grp AS "INSTRUMENT_GROUP_type_imnt_grp", 
anon_1."IMNT_GRP_MEMBERS_id_imnt_grp" AS "anon_1_IMNT_GRP_MEMBERS__1" 
FROM (SELECT IMNT_GRP_MEMBERS.id_imnt_grp AS "IMNT_GRP_MEMBERS_id_imnt_grp" 
    FROM IMNT_GRP_MEMBERS 
    WHERE 452 = IMNT_GRP_MEMBERS.id_imnt) AS anon_1 
    JOIN INSTRUMENT_GROUP ON INSTRUMENT_GROUP.id_imnt_grp = anon_1."IMNT_GRP_MEMBERS_id_imnt_grp" 
    ORDER BY anon_1."IMNT_GRP_MEMBERS_id_imnt_grp"`

However, it wont run via sqlalchemy, using a Sybase 15.5 driver via pyodbc. However, it runs fine via SQuirreL SQL using a jconnect driver.

Any ideas why this would be or how to fix?

Comment: "*it won't run*" is not a valid error message. What exactly is not working? Any error messages? Wrong results?

Comment: there can be any number of syntactical quirks which cause a failure here, I'm looking at that "452=<somecolumn>" in there which on some backends we need to switch.   But yes we'd need the error message fully here.   Sybase is a little-used backend with SQLAlchemy, and Sybase itself is an older, quirkier database, so there can be a lot of things going wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

If you are performing an INNER JOIN then try changing the JOIN part of the query like this by adding the word INNER before the JOIN.

```
anon_1 INNER JOIN INSTRUMENT_GROUP 
ON INSTRUMENT_GROUP.id_imnt_grp = anon_1."IMNT_GRP_MEMBERS_id_imnt_grp"
```

If it is a LEFT or RIGHT OUTER JOIN then change it accordingly also. LEFT JOIN or RIGHT JOIN for example.

Comment: The INNER keyword is optional. `JOIN` is the same thing as `INNER JOIN`